React Native - Android home screen widget update
More like asking for an advice where to start researching. I have never programmed native Android, just using React Native and have little expirience when need to adjust something native way. So now I took a step into native part of Android and I'm trying to create an home screen widget. I have created an widget and set minimum update of android:updatePeriodMillis (30 mins), but now I want to make a step further and idea is to implement Firebase/firestore into React Native app and create listener that will be notified when some collection document is pushed. Any advice what is best option to start with?
My idea is to create some app background actions that will serve as firestore listeners and create bridge between RN and Android with shared storage, I don't know if thats a good idea or there is some better way to do it?
Thanks in advance!
